# Error with Persistence Entity bean class inside invoked method after re-deploy: beans.Users cannot be cast to beans.Users

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, persistence, javabeans

i wrote `@AroundInvoke` method  to invoke methods of `Stateless` Restful API, the invoke method contain `EntityManager` for create named query for row inside table , and after that return it using `Entity Bean` Class , 
the problem is : My code Work fine when i start `Glassfish` from `Netbeans` for the first time , but when edit any thing inside the project , and `Netbeans` auto deploy the project to the `Glassfish` Server , and when i try to visit the `Stateless Restfult API Again` which have invoked methods , then my code don't work fine again it throw this exception:

> beans.Users cannot be cast to beans.Users

and it don't work again until i restart the `Glassfish` Server Again.

my Invoke Class :

```
public class AuthInterceptor{

    @AroundInvoke
    private Object initialize(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception{
            EntityManager EM = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("APIPU").createEntityManager();
            Query query = EM.createNamedQuery("Users.fetchbyToken");
            query.setParameter("token", token);

            Users User = (Users) query.getSingleResult();
            EM.refresh(User);
            EM.detach(User);

            // ..... continue other codes

    }
}
```

my Statless Restful API:

```
@Interceptors(AuthInterceptor.class)
@Stateless
@Path("User")
public class UserAPI{

  @GET
  @Produces("text/plain")
  public String test(){
    return "Hi..";
  }
}
```

my Users.class entity bean Sample :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS", schema = "APP")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Users.fetchbyToken", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.token = :token")
})
public class Users implements Serializable {
    // ... continue code..
}
```

Any explain please ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a classloader issue, what the error says is that your container has loaded the same class definition from two different places and is trying to cast the one to the other, i.e. your container has two `Users` classes with the exact same name, check the configuration of your project in netbeans